# Querying List<Coordinate> from Sitecore to SOLR

Tags: solr, computed-field

I have defined a Sitecore index field as below

```
[IndexField("_coordinates")]
public List<Coordinate> DealLocations { get; set; }
```

When I execute a query like

```
queryable.OrderByDistance(s => s.DealLocations, new Coordinate(latitude, longitude))
```

I got an exception in SOLR log as below

> ERROR Solr Error : [The field _coordinates_sm does not support spatial
>   filtering] - Query attempted: [({!geofilt pt=25.1406,55.1917
>   sfield=_coordinates_sm d=0 score=distance filter=false} AND
>   _template:(f250acc7e16e4f6cb7b8a2e6f41a6bf4))]

It's working fine with a single `Coordinate` but when I define the field `List<Coordinate>`, I am getting an exception.

Is there any way, we can compare more than one Coordinates or list of Coordinates in SOLR query?

Comment: Is your goal is to sort DealLocations list values based on some coordinates? I think the error is valid because field _coordinates_sm in this case is not a Coordinate type but it is a list of Coordinate type which does not support spatial filtering.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: How you are storing multiple coordinates for an item in Sitecore? are these coordinates stored as child items or stored as a field using treelist of multi list?

Comment: It is stored as multilist field for an item.

Comment: The solution i can suggest is to break each coordinate in its own index document so that you can run your spatial search against it. To achieve that either add coordinates as child items (instead of multi list), this way you can utilize indexing functionality/customisation already exists, other way can be to write your own crawler which will take care of creating multiple index document for that multlist field (i have not tried second approach but i think it is possible.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I think, this shoul work. Post your comment as answer and i can mark it accepted. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above in comments, you goal here is to filter an indexed document based on some coordinate from a list of coordinates, to achieve that you should break each coordinate in its own index document so that you can run your spatial search against it. I would suggest to either add coordinates as child items (instead of multi list), this way you can utilize indexing functionality/customisation already exists, other way will be to write your own crawler which will take care of creating multiple index document for that multlist field (i have not tried second approach but i think it is possible).